# How can I overlay 2 normal distribution curves on the same plot?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I'm brand new to R, and I'm facing a problem without much in- class resources. I need to do something that I'm sure is very simple. Can someone point me in the right direction? This is my task:

> Let X denote the monthly return on Microsoft Stock and let Y denote
>   the monthly return on Starbucks stock. Assume that X∼N(0.05,(0.10)2)
>   and Y∼N(0.025,(0.05)2).
>
> Using a grid of values between –0.25 and 0.35, plot the normal curves
>   for X and Y. Make sure that both normal curves are on the same plot.

I've only been able to get a randomly generated normal distribution generated, but not both on the same plot, and not by specifying mean and st dev. Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the functions lines or points, i.e.

```
s <- seq(-.25,.35,0.01)
plot(s, dnorm(s,mean1, sd1), type="l")
lines(s, dnorm(s,mean2, sd2), col="red")
```

also, check the function par (using 
    ?par
)
for plotting options, common options include labels (xlab/ylab), plotlimits (xlim/ylim), colors(col), etc...

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options

### Using base R

- You can use the `plot.function` method (which calls `curve` to plot a function). This is what is called if you call `plot(functionname)`

You will probably need to roll your own function so this will work. Also, you will need to set up the `ylim` so the whole range of both functions is shown.

```
# for example
fooX <- function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.1)
plot(fooX, from = -0.25, to = 0.35)
# I will leave the definition of fooY as an exercise.
fooY <- function(x) {# fill this is as you think fit!}
# see what it looks like
plot(fooY, from = -0.25, to = 0.35)
# now set appropriate ylim (left as an exercise)
# bonus marks if you work out a method that doesn't require this!
myYLim <- c(0, appropriateValue)
# now plot
plot(fooX, from = -0.25, to = 0.35, ylim = myYLim)
# add the second plot, (note add = TRUE)
plot(fooY, from = -0.25, to = 0.35, add = TRUE)
```

### Using ggplot2

`ggplot`  has a function `stat_function` that will impose a function on a plot. The examples in `?stat_function` show how to add two Normal pdf functions with different means to the same plot.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @mnel, we can use ggplot2 to plot several normal distributions in one plot. (I found this post is quite old, but I didn't find an easy answer to this question after searching in some other posts, so I would like to post an answer here)

```
base <- ggplot() + xlim(-10, 10)
base +
  geom_function(aes(colour = "Original prior"), fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 1, sd = 2)) +
  geom_function(aes(colour = "Prior 1"), fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 2, sd = 2)) +
  geom_function(aes(colour = "Prior 2"), fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 3, sd = 4)) +
  geom_function(aes(colour = "Prior 3"), fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 4, sd = 2))
```

[normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWWsV.png)